# SQL create extra column which gets data from the table two columns

Tags: sql

I have a query which have two fields that I would like to combine as a new column.
On excel it goes something like this

```
=CONCATENATE([@CompanyID],[@Year],[@month])
```

But I don't know how to create this formula on sql that the output would be like

NEW ID = 88201911  aka 88=companyID 2019=year 11=month

Example code

```
Select 
companyID,
invoicedate,
month(invoicedate) as month,
year(invoicedate) as year,
concat('companyID','month','year')
 from accounting
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot re-use a column alias in the same `select`.  So you need to repeat the expressions:

```
month(invoicedate) as month,
year(invoicedate) as year,
concat(companyID, month(invoicedate), year(invoicedate))
```

In addition, *never* use single quotes to refer to columns.  They should only be used for string and date constants.